# Where did the bracket notation for vectors come from and is using parentheses to represent vectors valid?

Tags: vectors, math-history

In class I learned that a vector can be represented using <>, a column vector, and unit vector notation. However, one of the old math books that I study from notes that a vector in unit vector form can be represented with parantheses:

"*Let $n$ be a positive integer. An ordered n-tuple of real numbers $$(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$$ is called a vector in n-space. The set of all such vectors, $a_i$ real, under operations to be explained, is called Euclidean n-space, $E^n$.*"

This book is **Calculus And Analytic Geometry Fourth Edition (1968) by George B. Thomas, Jr.**

Is this parentheses notation still used? If so, is it uncommon?

Comment: While totally anecdotal, I see the $(),[]$ notations most often. $<>$, not so much.

Comment: That is interesting. I've only seen the column notation,  and the $<>$ used most often.

Comment: This question belongs on hsm.se.

Answer (score -1):

This is the standard notation in quantum mechanics. It's great, because it allows to incorporate operators as well.

Copied from [Wikipedia](http://Bra%E2%80%93ket%20notation%20was%20effectively%20established%20in%201939%20by%20Paul%20Dirac[1][2]%20and%20is%20thus%20also%20known%20as%20the%20Dirac%20notation.)

> Bra–ket notation was effectively established in 1939 by Paul
>   Dirac[1](http://Bra%E2%80%93ket%20notation%20was%20effectively%20established%20in%201939%20by%20Paul%20Dirac[1][2]%20and%20is%20thus%20also%20known%20as%20the%20Dirac%20notation.)[2] and is thus also known as the Dirac notation.